# spark program to find the city with maximum population

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

Input files contains rows like below (state,city,population):

```
west bengal,kolkata,150000
karnataka,bangalore,200000
karnataka,mangalore,80000
west bengal,bongaon,50000
delhi,new delhi,100000
delhi,gurgaon,200000
```

I have to write a Spark (Apache Spark) program in both Python and Scala to find the city with maximum population. Output will be like this:

```
west bengal,kolkata,150000
karnataka,bangalore,200000
delhi,new delhi,100000
```

So I need a three column output for each state. It's easy for me to get the output like this:

```
west bengal,15000
karnataka,200000
delhi,100000
```

But to get the city having maximum population is getting difficult.

Comment: It's always helpful if you include what you've already tried (including code snippets) in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla `pyspark`, map your data to a pair RDD where the state is the key, and the value is the tuple (city, population). Then `reduceByKey` to keep the largest city. Beware, in the case of cities with the same population it will keep the first one it encounters.

`rdd.map(lambda reg: (reg[0],[reg[1],reg[2]]))
   .reduceByKey(lambda v1,v2: ( v1 if v1[1] >= v2[1] else v2))`

The results with your data look like this:

`[('delhi', ['gurgaon', 200000]),
 ('west bengal', ['kolkata', 150000]),
 ('karnataka', ['bangalore', 200000])]`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
>>> sc = spark.sparkContext
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ['west bengal','kolkata',150000],
    ['karnataka','bangalore',200000],
    ['karnataka','mangalore',80000],
    ['west bengal','bongaon',50000],
    ['delhi','new delhi',100000],
    ['delhi','gurgaon',200000],
])

>>> df = rdd.toDF(['state','city','population'])
>>> df.show()
+-----------+---------+----------+
|      state|     city|population|
+-----------+---------+----------+
|west bengal|  kolkata|    150000|
|  karnataka|bangalore|    200000|
|  karnataka|mangalore|     80000|
|west bengal|  bongaon|     50000|
|      delhi|new delhi|    100000|
|      delhi|  gurgaon|    200000|
+-----------+---------+----------+


>>> df.groupBy('city').max('population').show()
+---------+---------------+
|     city|max(population)|
+---------+---------------+
|bangalore|         200000|
|  kolkata|         150000|
|  gurgaon|         200000|
|mangalore|          80000|
|new delhi|         100000|
|  bongaon|          50000|
+---------+---------------+

>>> df.groupBy('state').max('population').show()
+-----------+---------------+
|      state|max(population)|
+-----------+---------------+
|      delhi|         200000|
|west bengal|         150000|
|  karnataka|         200000|
+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Actually I wanted three columns in each row of the output having the state, name of the city having max population and the corresponding population.